# jQuery works on jsFiddle doesn't work on wesite

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that works in jsFiddle, but doesn't work on an actual website and I cannot think of anything more to do.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flish/GB5Xm/)

and here is the [website](http://ro-bot.fr/flish/next.html)

I need a checkbox that when clicked will in turn check a number of other checkboxes.

```
$("form input[id='selectall']").click(function () {
    var inputs = $("form input[class='produse4export']");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (this.checked) {
            inputs[i].checked = true;
            checkme();
        } else {
            inputs[i].checked = false;
            uncheckme();
        }
    }
});
```

When these checkboxes are checked (all at once), they have to enable other checkboxes. When they are unchecked the rest of the checkboxes have to be again disabled and unchecked (if they were checked).

Kinda hard to explain, but both the fiddle and the webpage are easy to read. Why doesn't it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fiddle, you are binding the event on page load. On your page, you are attempting to do it while parsing the page itself.

On you page, change the event handler binding code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form input[id='selectall']").click(function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your `script` block to **below** the elements it acts on.

The reason it works on jsFiddle is that jsFiddle has a <s>truly brain dead</s> *surprising* default behavior, which is to put all of your script in a function called from the `window#load` event. (You can see this on the left-hand side, it's the second select box from the top.) So on jsFiddle, your script code isn't running until after all the HTML has been parsed and the elements exist. But on your website, you're putting the code **above** the elements it acts on, and so when you try to go get them, they don't exist yet.

The mantra for where to put things is: "Styles, content, scripts." Put your stylesheets (both inline and links) at the top of the document, the content in the body (obviously), and your scripts at the bottom, after all the content. That way, the elements exist in the DOM when your script runs.

See also:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure Library engineers on when DOM elements are ready for scripting](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

Comment: @flish: No worries. (You understand I was talking about the jsFiddle default setting, not *your use* of jsFiddle.)

Comment: It's not really braindead, as you can control, at what point are scripts included.

Comment: @Nordvind: I said the *default* was brain-dead. :-) I would default to almost anything other than the `window#load` event (ideally, just before end of `body`).