# Javascript, HTML, and CSS: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create some collapsible sections on a web page and I think I am doing something wrong in the Javascript code I am using. I am relatively new at developing custom web pages and I've tried everything I can think of to get to this to work.

So far, the collapsible content correctly follows the CSS code to not display. I just can't seem to get the button to display the content when I click on it.

I appreciate any help you all are able to provide.

```css
.collapsiblecontent {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
}

.collapsible button.collapsible {
  background-color: #00000000;
  border: 0;
  color: #00000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover button.collapsible {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var collapsiblecontent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (collapsiblecontent.style.display === "block") {
      collapsiblecontent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      collapsiblecontent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}/
// ]]></script>
<h2><strong>Heading</strong></h2>
<div class="content" style="font-size: 110%;"><button type="button" class="collapsible">Button 1:</button>
<div class="collapsiblecontent">
<p>Content Example 1.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Button 2:</button>
<div class="collapsiblecontent">
<p>Content Example 2.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Button 3:</button>
<div class="collapsiblecontent">
<p>Content Example 3.</p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Button 4:</button>
<div class="collapsiblecontent">
<p>Content Example 4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine.

Comment: After @pai.not.pi's edit, appears to be ok.

Comment: @pai.not.pi You're right. Unfortunately, this means I have no idea why this isn't working on my end.

Comment: I rolled back the question since an edit fixed it and would have made this question irrelevant. @pai.not.pi if you have a fix for it, don't edit the question, add it as an answer AND what you did to fix it.

Comment: @BrianH  EDIT: your JavaScript is loading too early and the elements you are targeting don't exist yet. Put the javascript after all the content before the closing `</body>` tag. Also, you have a typo with `}/` on the second to last line.

Comment: @disinfor I just moved it and now it is working correctly now. Thank you! EDIT: Your explanation makes a lot of sense to me. That is really useful to know.

Comment: It's really only because the elements don't exist yet for the JS to parse. The DOM is read top to bottom, so it sees your JS, but the JS can't get `elementsByClassName` since they don't exist yet. Check out this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633642/1172189

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery works on jsFiddle doesn't work on wesite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633620/jquery-works-on-jsfiddle-doesnt-work-on-wesite)

Comment: @disinfor Yes! Thank you so much!